# Domain and Subdomain Full Page URL In Reports

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

I followed the information in this [manual](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012243?hl=en) and created an advanced filter. I can see Full Page URL. But I have a problem with this external link icon.

In `Behavior > Site Content > All Pages`

All external links are incorrect:

1. example.com > example.comexample.com
2. example.com/contact > example.comexample.com/contact
3. blog.example.com > example.comblog.example.com
4. example.com/about > example.comexample.com/about

Is there any way to correct this? Or am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is a drawback of the URL Rewrite filter. It does not involve anything in tracking, only that functionality of opening the page through that icon cannot be used. This is because in the Analytics view settings you can indicate only one domain and that is what Analytics automatically appends to the URL when you click on that icon.